# Render React Server Side

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, environment-variables

I am using [react.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) in [meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/) to render a map, but I need to make sure that no-one uses my secret token, and pass in some secure variable instead. Currently, the following code from `/client/main.js` is done on the client. I tried copying it over, but am getting `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. How can I implement this code on the server?

**From /client/main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var NewComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="map" />
    );      
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
    // SEE BELOW FOR THE TOKEN...
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjsecretxODBxMDA4dHU0bTVwOThiNjBqbCJ9.ALkY_spgnw5ZqOtoken';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, -74.50], 9);   
  },  
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<NewComponent />, document.getElementById('map-container'));
});
```

**From /client/main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=secret3tze-UVizTCUDjAhtoken71zY&libraries=places" async defer></script>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am pretty certain that you cannot securely hide the token without mixing some sort of authentication from a server.

Comment: [Flow Router SSR](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/tree/ssr) can probably do this, but unfortunately I can't tell how exactly.